# JMS integration testing

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, integration-testing, spring-jms

I am trying to write an integration test for JMS service which looks like something like this.

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
 public void receiveMessage(Email message) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        sendEmail(message);
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,"Failed to deliver email",e);
        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(Optional.of(retryInterval).orElse(5)));
        throw e;
    }
}

private void sendEmail(Email message){
    ...............
}
```

First of all, can I mock this some how? I tried mocking it, but when I send a message the spring boot application is calling the actual JMS bean not the mock one. Seems like this is not possible. 
Even if this is not possible, can I at least aoutowire the bean and somehow check if the receiveMessage method is being invoked. Furthermore, if it is being invoked, the sendEmail part should be faked so that it does not do any work. I have a few ideas such as creating a subclass for testing, but not happy with either of them. So wanted to if you can suggest me a better work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use different profiles for say development, integration test and production and annotate the different components and your integration test class accordingly.

```
@Component
@Profile("it")
public class MessageReceiverIT {

    @JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(SimpleMessage email) {
        log.info("Integration test pretend to receive {}", email);
// (...)
```

This is the Integration test that uses the same Application class as the real Application, but if a message is received the `MessageReceiverIT.receiveMessage()` method will be invoked instead of the production component:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
public class JmsIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void testSend() throws Exception{
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("mailbox", new SimpleMessage("it", "we need more IT"));
// (...)
```

Also check out [Spring Boot Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) for alternative approaches such as the use of `@TestConfiguration`. I'm using Spring Boot in my examples, but there should be similar approaches if you have a none Spring Boot Application.

Comment: Actually, I used similar approach and used active mq as in memory messaging queue. Created two profiles, test and prod from where I do init things differently.